# Field with author link in node

Tags: 7, users

i am building a website where many users will be able to add specific content. I want each content-node to have a link to the the authors profile page. I am using profile2 for users profiles and the alias of link in the node must be the "Company Name" field and not the username.

How can i achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use Views, and place that view towards the bottom of the article or that content type?

The views will be based on a user relationship with the node uid (the author's user id).

All those fields you require you can add to the user profile (admin/config/people/accounts/fields) - Company Name, Byline etc etc? And then display them via views.

Comment: It's 7 in the morning, so I'm quite groggy...If my answer doesn't apply, I'm sorry. If it makes sense and you still have doubts leave a comment, and I will update the answer in detail by the end of day.

Answer (score 0):

create a template file for your content type, in your theme folder. it should be something like `node--node_type.tpl.php` . In that file you should have access to all the node's fields.

You can start by using the default `node.tpl.php` as an example. More about templates you can find [here](http://drupal.org/node/1089656).

**EDIT:**

in your default `node.tpl.php` you could find something like this:

```
// this is taken from the omega theme
<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
  <footer class="submitted"><?php print $date; ?> -- <?php print $name; ?></footer>
<?php endif; ?>
```

so instead of `print $name` you could do something like `print l('your custom field value', 'user/' . $node->uid)`

Comment: well, i am able to see the link but the problem is that i want to replace the description of the link with a field of the users profile. For example i have the link user44 wich links to user profile node. I want to replace "user44" with the Company Name. Company name is a field in the profile2. I dont know if my question is clear enough.

Comment: yeah, it's clear but I think you did not understood what I was trying to say. I edited the answer, maybe this will be more clear.